# rxjs, ignoring one pipe

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am trying to create generic pipe that will catch errors and will affect other pipes.

Our producer:

```
const producer = () => of(1, 2).pipe(
            map((primitiveValue: number) => {
                if (primitiveValue === 2) {
                    return throwError(primitiveValue)
                }
                return {value: primitiveValue};
            }),
        );
```

This pipe will be attached to any producer, and will listen for errors:

```
const genericDecorator = (observable) =>
            observable
                .pipe(
                    catchError((primitiveValue) => {
                        return of('some error ' + primitiveValue)
                    })
                );
```

Subscription:

```
genericDecorator(producer())
                .pipe(
                    map((wrapped) => {
                        return wrapped.value;
                    })
                )
                .subscribe((value) => {
                    result.push(value)
                });
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
result = [1, 'some error 2']
```

And what I got is

```
result = [1, undefined]
```

This seems logical, but is there any way to skip one pipe?

Comment: What do you mean by "skip one pipe"?

Comment: returning value immediately to the subscriber

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could just replace the value returned by `catchError`:

```
catchError((primitiveValue) => {
  return of({ value: 'some error ' + primitiveValue })
})
```

Comment: Its not solution for me. I dont want to couple value returned by catchError to value returned by any other observable

Comment: Then you can check `typeof wrapped === 'object'` inside `map`

Comment: This still will couple them together. I dont want to change second pipe in any way. Was thinking is there any operator that can help achieving this.

Comment: ... or use `catchError` after `map`. There's no way you just "can skip" operators.